# Intro.js React wrapper not parsing source map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intro.js

I am following the tutorial example from [React.js Onboarding Using Intro.js](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/react-js-onboarding-using-intro-js-4b03aa2f584e) however when I look at my page the tooltip is not popping up and my terminal is giving the following errors:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/intro.js/intro.module.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/Users/necolanch/Documents/IntroJS/onboarding/node_modules/intro.js/intro.module.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/necolanch/Documents/IntroJS/onboarding/node_modules/intro.js/intro.module.js.map'

WARNING in ./node_modules/intro.js/introjs.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/intro.js/introjs.css)
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/Users/necolanch/Documents/IntroJS/onboarding/node_modules/intro.js/introjs.css.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/necolanch/Documents/IntroJS/onboarding/node_modules/intro.js/introjs.css.map'
```

The following image link is what shows when I run the server:

[Tooltip does not show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsgUe.png)

Comment: any luck fixing this?

Comment: Not at the moment. I found an alternative library that is similar if you are wanting to provide a guide/tour for your app/website.

ShepherdJS: https://shepherdjs.dev/
To use in React: https://github.com/shipshapecode/react-shepherd

Comment: I ended up using GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false in the environment before calling the build on the target project, this removed the warnings.

Comment: Any updates on this ?

Comment: @Erick Maybe try what M.Imran Mamda said, I have not personally. I started using the ShepherdJS and like that quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like warning caused by `create-react-app` and **Webpack 5.x**

To remove the warning simply add `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` to your `.env` file, and then stop and start your project.

Also everything works fine for me on server.

Comment: https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/issues/1595. The issue is still present on the latest version even though it has been closed.
I am not using CRA and webpack v5 but still getting the issue